# calign child forest package with folder option

Tags: alignment, forest

I used the forest package with the folder option to create a tree which looks like this:

[image: forest with folder option]

I want to align the small vertical lines of "Text 1" and "Text 1.2".
Using `calign = child` and `calign child = center` aligns the lines of "Text 1" and the children of "Text 1.2". I assume it has something to do with the folder option.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
    forked edges,
    where={level()<1}{}{
        folder,
        grow'=east,
        align=left,
        l=20pt,
        s sep=-5pt
        }
        [Text 1, calign = child, calign child = 2
            [Text 1.1
                [Text 1.1.1]
                [Text 1.1.2]
                [Text 1.1.3]
                [Text 1.1.4]
                [Text 1.1.5]
                [Text 1.1.6]
                [Text 1.1.7]
            ]
            [Text 1.2
                [Text 1.2.1]
                [Text 1.2.2]
                [Text 1.2.3]
            ]
            [Text 1.3]
            [Text 1.4]
    ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `calign = child edge` instead of `calign = child`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
    forked edges,
    where={level()<1}{}{
        folder,
        grow'=east,
        align=left,
        l=20pt,
        s sep=-5pt
        }
        [Text 1, calign = child edge, calign child = 2
            [Text 1.1
                [Text 1.1.1]
                [Text 1.1.2]
                [Text 1.1.3]
                [Text 1.1.4]
                [Text 1.1.5]
                [Text 1.1.6]
                [Text 1.1.7]
            ]
            [Text 1.2
                [Text 1.2.1]
                [Text 1.2.2]
                [Text 1.2.3]
            ]
            [Text 1.3]
            [Text 1.4]
    ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```